# Sieve of Eratosthenes C++ Implementation (from Principles of Programming Soustrup C++ book)

Tags: c++

I have tried my own implementation of the algorithm, and while it works, I'm sure it's not working as the algorithm is supposed to be. Here is the code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    vector<int> primes;
    int input; 

    cin >> input;
    
    for (int i =2;i<input;++i)
        primes.push_back(i);
    
    for (int j = 0; j<sqrt(input);++j)
        for (int i =j; i<primes.size();++i)
            if (i==j)
            {
            }
            else if (primes[i] % primes[j] == 0)
                primes.erase(primes.begin() + (i));
    
    cout << "Prime numbers are: "<<primes.size()<<endl;
    
    for (int j =0;j<primes.size();++j)
        cout <<primes[j]<<"; ";
}
```

While I found this solution, this does not allow me to go from multiples of 2/3/5/7 and it only takes iteratively by 1 and it's hard to implement since the prime vector size is always changing.

I don't understand how you " mark " the non-prime numbers and then you remove those and remaining with primes, so this is the reasoning of primes.erase function.

If I would list the non-prime numbers found in another vector, and after I finish finding all non prime numbers, would it make it more efficient to substract from a vector of elements 1,2...n the non-prime vectors? In this case, we are talking of functions that were not described so far in the book.

Comment: This is not [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). For that you need array of boolean values indicating if value of given index is prime or not. You do not erase anything just marking index true or false.

Comment: i dont understand your code, but `j` going till `sqrt(input)` because thats the largest factor you need to consider and then using `j` as index into a vector from which you erase elements during the iteration looks wrong. In one place you use `j` for the factor, then as index into the vector.

Comment: Tactical note: `sqrt` can be expensive. Since `input` doesn't change, `sqrt(input)` isn't going to change. Compute it once and cache. Compare `j` with the cached value. A smart compiler could do this for you. If the value is going to change, often it's better to square the other value (eg, `j*j< input`)

Comment: Other tactical note: putting all potential candidates in a dynamic container and then deleting the failed ones is way more expensive than just generating the values to test as you go.